# Converting string to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to convert the string to dict. Below is the single string which is the output of the powershell script. I want to get the below data in dictionary format as shown below. Name (AAA and WWW) as key and other value including name as value set of dict. Is there any way to get it ?

```
Name                   : AAA
HostName            : BBB
DistinguishedName      : CCC
Date          : 5/26/2020 6:47:12 PM
OS        : DDD
Version : 7 (900)



Name                   : WWW
HostName            : QQQ
DistinguishedName      : RRR
Date          : 7/14/2020 7:07:07 AM
OS       : TTT
Version : 6 (900)
```

OUTPUT :

```
dic = {'AAA' : ['AAA' , 'BBB' , 'CCC', '5/26/2020 6:47:12 PM' , 'DDD', '7 (900)'] , 'WWW' : ['WWW', 'QQQ', 'RRR' , '7/14/2020 7:07:07 AM', 'TTT', ' 6 (900)'] }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: @Renat, I haven't got much idea.. tried with splitting this string... removed the null and added everything in the list and then tried to get it in the dict format but it dint worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
input_string = """
Name                   : AAA
HostName            : BBB
DistinguishedName      : CCC
Date          : 5/26/2020 6:47:12 PM
OS        : DDD
Version : 7 (900)



Name                   : WWW
HostName            : QQQ
DistinguishedName      : RRR
Date          : 7/14/2020 7:07:07 AM
OS       : TTT
Version : 6 (900)
"""

splited = input_string.split("\nName                   :")
splited = filter(lambda x: x not in ["\n", ""], splited)


result = dict()


for i in splited:
    j = i.split("\n")
    key = j[0].replace(" ", "")
    
    result_item = [key]
    jj = i.replace(key, "")
    
    for v in jj.split("\n"):
        if ":" in v:
            result_item.append(v.split(": ")[1].strip())
    
    result[key] = result_item

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help!!

```
s = """Name                   : AAA
HostName            : BBB
DistinguishedName      : CCC
Date          : 5/26/2020 6:47:12 PM
OS        : DDD
Version : 7 (900)
Name                   : WWW
HostName            : QQQ
DistinguishedName      : RRR
Date          : 7/14/2020 7:07:07 AM
OS       : TTT
Version : 6 (900)
Name                   : RRR
HostName            : QQQ
DistinguishedName      : RRR
Date          : 7/14/2020 7:07:07 AM
OS       : TTT
Version : 6 (900)"""

s1 = s.replace(' ','')
l = s1.split('\n')

glbl_dict = {}
temp_list = []
glbl_list = []

for i in l:
    check = i.split(':')
    if check[0] == 'Name':
    
        if temp_list != []:
            glbl_list.append(temp_list)
        
        temp_list = []
        temp_list.append(check[-1])
    
    else:
        temp_list.append(check[-1])
    
glbl_list.append(temp_list)

for i in glbl_list:
    glbl_dict[i[0]] = i
    
print(glbl_dict)
# sample output
# {'AAA': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', '12PM', 'DDD', '7(900)'], 'WWW': ['WWW', 'QQQ', 'RRR', '07AM', 'TTT', '6(900)'], 'RRR': ['RRR', 'QQQ', 'RRR', '07AM', 'TTT', '6(900)']}
```

Comment: Thank you. but its splitting with \n so even if its a single sentence the o/p will be as 2 diff value. @mayankgupta